# Identify an USAF transport aircraft in Greenland around 1960

Tags: military, propeller, aircraft-identification, us-air-force

[image: USAF]Could anybody help me identify this aircraft?
It was photographed in Greenland around 1960.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.StackExchange!

Comment: Satoshi, it appears that you've two accounts (an unregistered one from where you posted the question and a registered one from where you edited the question). Please visit [this URL](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to merge the accounts.

Answer (score 12):

That is the **Douglas DC-6 / C-118/R6D Liftmaster**.

This specific plane was built in June 1947 with modifications for [presidential use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Force_One#Late_1940s_and_1950s). It is well known for flying US President Truman. It was the first presidential aircraft that received a distinctive exterior.

It actively served USAF until 1965 when it was transfered to an USAF museum. It is now on display at USAF museum in Dayton, Ohio, USA.

[[Source]](https://www.aerialvisuals.ca/AirframeDossier.php?Serial=31150)

[image: Exterior View]
[image: Cockpit View]
[image: Interior View]

[[Image Source]](https://www.nationalmuseum.af.mil/Visit/Museum-Exhibits/Fact-Sheets/Display/Article/195804/douglas-vc-118-independence/)

Comment: I'm not convinced OP photo is a C-118. It might be a C-54.  [I'm looking at the prop hub](https://www.citamn.afrc.af.mil/Features/Article/195216/preserving-history-airmen-restore-aircraft-to-its-former-glory/) and the C-118 had a spinner that covered the prop shank more than I can tell here. I'm not certain; does anyone have more afirmation?

Comment: @radarbob, The C-54 had round passenger windows, and only one window behind the rear door. See for example https://www.nationalmuseum.af.mil/Visit/Museum-Exhibits/Fact-Sheets/Display/Article/195813/douglas-vc-54c-sacred-cow/ .